# Send Hashtable using UDP c#

Tags: c#, arrays, casting, udp, hashtable

Hi i'm tring to send image & voice using udp. First of all i create `Hashtable` and contain image and voice data in this `Hashtable`. But I cant send this hashtable using udp in c#, 'cause the `Send` func of `UdpClient` only able to send `byte[]` array. So how can I send `Hashtable` using udp.

Also you can suggest type **cast methods** for `Hashtable` to `byte[]`.

Comment: I'm not an expert for sending images and voice over a UDP connection, but `HashTable` does not store the data you pass it, but hashes for it instead. This sounds like an [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. You don't want to cast your `HashTable` to anything, you need to use a different data type.

Comment: thank you so much @MaxPlay . Just now I want to know which data type will be best for converting between byte[] array?